# How can I typeset non-inline math in tables?

Tags: math-mode, tables

I have to typeset mathematics in table and want to avoid it being scaled down because I have to use inline math (`\( \)`). However, using `\[ \]` for example does not work. What is the best way to typeset tables with formulas, in such a way that the math is not scaled down?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ test \] % works

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\[ test  \] & \[ test \]\\ % doesn't work
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add `\displaystyle` within the inline math environment, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}  % fixes that \( \) are fragile, but not necessary with recent versions of LaTeX
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\( \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}   \) & \( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \) \\
\(\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}   \) & \( \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \)
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like your solution, it doesn't require changing all my columns to `p`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use `tabularx` or alternetively the `p`-column specifier if you want smaller columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}XX@{}}
\[ test  \] & \[ test \]
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use paragraph columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ test \] % works
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}}
\[ test  \] & \[ test \]\\ % works now
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation of the answer by @wh1t3 would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ test \] % works

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\parbox{2cm}{\[ test  \]} & \parbox{2cm}{\[ test \]}\\ % does work
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The solution consists here, as you can see in putting each equation into a box. With `\parbox` the width is a required parameter, so you will need to specify it as with `p` columns.

On the other hand you will not need any extra packages.

Comment: This requires guessing the width, which isn't necessary with `\(\displaystyle ...\)`.

Comment: same with `p` columns... :) Your solution is way more elegant, @egreg.